# How to change the command prompt font size in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: font-size

I see from an online search how to change the font size for the environment, but when I run programs, the font size for the program is still tiny.  How do I change that font size? Thanks!

[image: Small Program font size]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the top of the window and choose 'Defaults', edit the size settings, save and load the command window again

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c51am.png